# How to use socket.io in angular?and continuous communication using socket service in angular?

Tags: angular, socket.io

I'm new in angular.I want fetch continuous dynamic data from socket server.server side is fine but I'm not able to receive data from socket server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question with an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will work try this:**

**1.First you have to create component in angular like :**

**socketComponent.ts**

```
import { SocketDataService } from 'socketDataService';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-socket',
  templateUrl: './app-socket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-socket.component.css'],

})

export class SocketComponent implements OnInit {


  sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private socketDataService: SocketDataService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getSocketData();
    }

    getSocketData(): void {
    this.sub = this.socketDataService.getSocketData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.socketData = data
    })
  }
}
```

**2. You have to create service like :**

**socketService.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class SocketDataService {

    private socket;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
    }

    observer
    getSocketData(): Observable<any> {
        this.socket.on('socket-data', (res) => {
            this.observer.next(res);
        });
        return this.getSocketDataObservable();
    }
    getSocketDataObservable(): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            this.observer = observer;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple way

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

ngOnInit() {
  this.socket = io('hostname');

  this.socket.on('socket_event', (data) => {
   console.log(data);
                                }.bind(this));
}
```